Comedy about guy mistaken for spy and trained to replace him
I remember seeing a movie where some clueless guy is mistaken for a spy. Since he is not but the spy agency needs him, they train him to speak Czech or Slovak (he's supposed to meet some shady people in Czechoslovakia, quite possibly arm dealers). 
They first send him to a room with a dictionary and he starts learning. They watch him through a one way mirror, someone notes something like "He's eager to learn". Another one asks - "What's he saying?" and apparently the sentence he was practicing from the dictionary was something like "My vagina has an infection" (or whatever). He also has a sidekick from that agency helping him throughout the movie, a young woman. This was happening at night on paved streets, where they found him then sent to the meeting.
I saw it in the early 2000s, probably up to 2005 on TV and it was either a 90s or early 2000 movie. It's neither "The Man with One Red Shoe", nor "The Man Who Knew Too Little". The movie was in English, so I first went to these 2 since they had the "mistaken for a spy" idea behind them. Could be a TV movie since others I saw back then I managed to find on my own via Google searches.

It sounds a lot like "Bad Company" (2002).
Plot on Wikipedia:

When a mission to retrieve a stolen suitcase bomb goes bad, Central
  Intelligence Agency (CIA) agent Kevin Pope (Rock) is killed. Pope was
  working undercover as an antiquities dealer under the name Michael
  Turner. The CIA, which is desperate to complete the mission, discovers
  that Agent Pope had a twin brother, Jake Hayes (also Rock),...
After the CIA successfully persuades Hayes to participate and begins
  to train Hayes for a mission that is to take place in Prague, Czech
  Republic, they are initially dismayed by his lack of refinement.
After arriving in Prague, Hayes - posing as his dead brother - meets
  with the men selling the suitcase bomb. The seller, Adrik Vas, is an
  ex-Russian Army Colonel with ties to the Russian Mafia. When they
  return to their hotel, Hayes is greeted by his brother's ex-girlfriend
  Nicole (Garcelle Beauvais).

During training Chris Rock's character is watched through hidden cameras, and he also has to learn a foreign language.
Trailer:




Yes, this is it! I looked up the trailer too and recognized the chess hustler part and where Anthony Hopkins throws a glass of water on him to wake up.

Great! Please mark my answer above as the correct answer. Thank you!

Done! I wasn't sure exactly how this worked, this is my first time asking, I usually overdo Google when looking. This movie really is Chris Rock's style, just like Rush Hour
